# Custom Angular.js filter returning nothing in IE8 on ng-repeat, works fine in Chrome/FF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have written a custom filter to change the output of ng-repeat. We have a list of files in JSON and I am creating the links to assets from the filter, as the json builds them with just the filename and not the actual path.

**Filter**:

```
filter('readLink', [function(){
return function(text) {

    var myURI = [],
        newLink;
    text.split('/').forEach(function(uriItem) {
        myURI.push(uriItem);
    });

    newLink = myURI[3] + '/' + myURI[4] + '/' + myURI[5] + '/' + myURI[6];

    return newLink;
    }
}])
```

**HTML Binding**:

```
<ul class="sob-repeat">
  <li ng-repeat="sobitem in sobUT">
  <h4>{{sobitem.title}}</h4>
  {{sobitem.date}} - <a ng-href="{{sobitem.audio | audioFix}}">Listen</a> - <a ng-href="#/read/{{sobitem.transcript | readLink}}">Read</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In IE8 is comes up  while in **REAL BROWSERS** it works as expected. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not supported on IE 8, did you remember to [polyfill](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) it for IE 8? Or alternatively, use [`angular.forEach`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach).

Comment: Yes, it was the forEach that was breaking my filter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. change to `angular.forEach`didn't solve the problem. Instead, regular `for loop` solved the problem